# Hide Direct file Url in symfony

Tags: symfony1, tcpdf

I'm using tcpdf to generate pdf report. I have stored that report files under web root directory. Then I am displaying pdf by redirecting to that page like

Code: Select all
    http://sitename/pdf/student_record.pdf

I dont want to disclose the directory name pdf and filename. I want to set some duplicate name for that because of some security reasons. How can I do that using routing.yml?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do something like you would like to have. 
So, I extended sfActions with myActions and add method:

```
/**
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param string $mimetype
 * @return sfView::NONE
 */
public function downloadFile($path, $mimetype, sfRequest $request) {
    if (is_file($path) && is_readable($path)) {
        $this->setLayout(false);
        sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);
        $this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', $mimetype);
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Pragma: public', true);
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Expires', 0);
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Length', filesize($path));
        $this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders();
        file_put_contents(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/test.txt', var_export($_SERVER, 1) . 'TEST');
        if($request->isMethod(sfRequest::HEAD))
            $this->getResponse()->setContent('');
        else
            $this->getResponse()->setContent(file_get_contents($path));
    }
    else
        $this->forward404('Unreadable file', 'json');

    return sfView::NONE;
}
```

and used that method for actions from routing. For example, we have model Author and mp3 for it. So, in routing.yml:

```
author_show:
  url:       /api/authors/:id.:sf_format
  class:     sfDoctrineRoute
  options:   { model: Author, type: object }
  param:     { module: author, action show }
  requirements:
    sf_format: (?:mp3)
```

In action:

```
switch($request->getParameter('sf_format')) {
        case 'mp3':
            $path = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/authors/audio/' . $author->getAboutAudio();
            $mimetype = 'audio/mpeg';
            break;

        default:
            $this->forward500('Unknown format. Only mp3 format is available.', 'json');
    }
    return $this->downloadFile($path, $mimetype, $request);
```

Also, you can store it in some subfolder in uploads and secure it with .htaccess, like

```
deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the pdf outside of the webroot, then create a route and action that checks if the user may access it, then sets the correct headers for a pdf file and outputs it via `fpassthru()` or `readfile()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should'nt use symfony to upload files, while your web server can do it directly. For exemple, save your files in an external directory, like /path/to/pdf, then, in your virtualhost, add :

```
Alias /pdf /path/to/pdf
```

If you also want to change the name, you could use some kind of rewrite rule.